# Accidently deleted my EFI partion

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

I had Windows 10 and Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 installed in my laptop. Due to some problem occurring in Windows I decided to delete it during the process I accidentally deleted the EFI partition for Ubuntu. How can I restore it without reinstalling whole Ubuntu??

Comment: try this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't re-used the disk space, you should be able to recover the partition with [TestDisk.](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) After recovering the partition in this way, the NVRAM-based boot manager references might or might not work any more, so you may need to recover the system to bootability in one way or another. One way would be to use my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R to do a one-time boot and then create a new boot entry with `efibootmgr`. The command would be something like this:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi -L ubuntu
```

This creates a new boot entry for the `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` boot loader file on `/dev/sda1`. Change the `-d`, `-p`, and `-l` options as necessary for your system.

A caveat: The rEFInd USB flash drive and CD-R images I provide do not support Secure Boot. If it's enabled, you'll need to either disable it or [jump through some hoops](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) to get rEFInd to work with Secure Boot active. You can temporarily disable Secure Boot and then re-enable it later, if you like.

If you have overwritten the part of the disk that used to hold the ESP, your task is harder. You can still do a one-time boot using rEFInd, but you'll then need to create a new ESP and populate it with boot loaders for both Ubuntu (probably GRUB, but you could use rEFInd or something else) and Windows. If you have a backup of the ESP, restoring it should work. If not, you could use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to install a fresh GRUB or install rEFInd from its Debian package or PPA. For Windows boot recovery, you'll have to ask about this on a Windows forum. If possible, do the Windows recovery first, since Windows will set its boot loader as the default, and it won't provide an option to chainload to Ubuntu. GRUB and rEFInd, by contrast, both provide options to boot either Ubuntu or Windows. (Or they should; sometimes this doesn't work correctly.)